# Как записать результат Ajax запроса Wordpress?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Ну вот выбрал посетитель пару картинок на одной странице и нажал на кнопку "загрузить" и при помощи Ajax запроса передаю массив js. И тип работает , выводит 0, но вот как сделать , чтоб админ смог посмотреть какие картинки , какие запись , что вообще выбирают пользователи ?

Comment: Если в ключе "посмотреть что делают пользователи на сайте", то подключите Google Analytics и создайте цели для действий, которые вы хотите отслеживать https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415

Comment: ну к примеру посетитель/пользователь выбрал 5 картинок и нажал на кнопку "Загрузить" . AJAX запрос отправился и в Google Analytics будет видно, что выбрал посетитель?

Comment: В GA можно создавать цели - javascript события, выбор картинок так же можно отслеживать, просто на front'е нужно будет добавлять обработчики на действия.

Comment: Ок. буду пытаться как то справится, Но всё же , если без GA то как тогда еще можно справится, чтоб админ в админке увидел результат запроса?( просто спрашиваю из сильного интереса и еще потому что , если вдруг  GA не покатит )

Comment: Тут вариантов много, например собирать все действия пользователя к нему в `localStorage` на javascript, а потом с определённой периодичностью отправлять данные из localStorage на сервер для записи в БД. Или же при каждом действии делать отправку в БД, но это похуже будет, т.к. делать много запросов в БД не очень хорошо. Как отправлять данные в БД - в интернете очень много примеров, это обычные AJAX + PHP + mysql. Запись в БД можно организовать через WP хуки, к примеру `$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format);`

Comment: Да , ок , а где потом , в каком разделе, админ сможет увидеть это всё?

Comment: По правильному, нужнов  самой функции аякс завершать ее через `wp_send_json()`, тогда и 0 возвращать не будет, а кокретные данные.